# Limit the namespace access to clients in OPC UA connection

Tags: python, server, roles, opc-ua

Im setting a server un python by using the library asyncua.

I have multiple namespaces, one for each client and i need to limit the access to the nodes. For example, client1 can access to nodes in namespace1 but he cant access to nodes in namespace2.

I want the keep the idea of one server to multiple clients, the previous implementation was one service per client and was not a good idea for multiple reasons.

Some one could help me to set some policies, in the UserManager, RoleRuleset or something like that, to restrict access to certain spaces

hope someone could can helpme

This is my first approach to opcua, im open corrections and observations.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're looking to implement access control and security for your OPC UA server using the asyncua library in Python. Instead of creating a separate namespace for each client, you can implement Identity and Access Management (IAM) to manage access to nodes by users or clients. This approach is more scalable and flexible, especially when dealing with a large number of clients.

Here are some steps you can take to achieve this:

User Authentication: Implement user authentication to verify the identity of clients connecting to the server. You can use the UserManager in asyncua to manage user accounts. Each user should have a unique username and password.

User Roles: Define different roles for users based on their access requirements. For example, you can create roles like "Client1" and "Client2." Each role should have specific permissions associated with it.

Access Control Policies: Use RoleRulesets to define access control policies. RoleRulesets allow you to specify which roles can access specific nodes and what actions they can perform. For example, you can create rules that grant read or write access to nodes in certain namespaces to specific roles.

Apply Policies to Nodes: Assign the RoleRulesets to nodes in your server's address space. This is where you define which clients can access which nodes. For example, you can assign a RoleRuleset to nodes in namespace1 for Client1 and a different RoleRuleset to nodes in namespace2 for Client2.

User-Based Filtering: In your server code, implement filtering based on the authenticated user's role and apply these filters when clients access nodes. You can use the UserManager to get the user's role and then apply the appropriate access control based on the role.

Logging and Monitoring: Implement logging and monitoring to keep track of user activities and any access violations. This will help you maintain security and troubleshoot any issues.